# Simulink error: Cannot find implementation for block

Tags: matlab, simulink, hdl, hdl-coder

I am attempting to create a simple DDS/NCO to be used in an FPGA. I have a working DDS in simulink. But when I try to convert it to HDL using the HDL converter I receive the above error. The only problem is that the block for which I receive the that error does not exist in my design anymore. Closing and reopening the program has done nothing to update that. This error is normally received when a block is not compatible with the HDL coder. However I am fairly certain that all my other blocks are indeed compatible.

I am using Matlab R2014a if that is at all relevant

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried creating a new model and copying all the blocks from your model into it? It might be worth giving it a try, just to check. Don't forget to change the relevant settings in the model as well.

Comment: IN addition to what @am304 said, can you go and check if expanding HDL coder library in SIMULINK lib browser reveals all your blocks correctly? Try and add your `>> ver` command output on the question so that we know if HDL coder is fully available. There is a (dirty) hard way: go to the SIMULINK model `.xml` file and delete any reference that you can see for your old HDL block.

Comment: Strangely all it took to fix was a copy paste into a new simulink window and readjusting the model properties. Thanks for the advice.